# How to automatically add a one-to-many object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new at ASP.NET MVC and I'm having problems trying to insert a object 1xn automatically usining my method Create. I want to know how to insert the object RelUserHomes and I need the homeId but it'll exist only after the db.SaveChanges().

Here's a snippet:

#### Controller Homes

```
[HttpPost]    
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]    
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "HomeId,Name")] Home home)    
{    
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {    
         db.Homes.Add(home);    
         RelUserHomes relUserHomes = new RelUserHomes();  

        // I did this because I need the homeId to insert this object    
         relUserHomes.HomeId = db.SaveChanges();    
         relUserHomes.Email = Session["Email"].ToString();
         relUserHomes.IsAdmin = true;
         db.RelUserHomes.Add(relUserHomes);    
         db.SaveChanges();    
    }
    return View(home);
}
```

#### Model RelUserHomes

```
public class RelUserHomes
{
    [Key]
    public int RelUserHomesId { get; set; }

    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int HomeId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public Home Homes { get; set; }
}
```

#### Application DBContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> 
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("PrimoEntities")
    {
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
           // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
            var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);
            var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);
            var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);
            // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
            throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
        }
     }

     public DbSet<Home> Homes { get; set; }

     public DbSet<RelUserHomes> RelUserHomes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does "1xn" mean?

Comment: @JohnSaunders this means a relationship one-to-many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `RelUserHomes` entity has a foreign key relationship pointing to a `Home` entity, the `Home` object must be added to the database first, so that it is assigned a `HomeId` value. You can simply add a `db.SaveChanges()` a little earlier in the code, and then assign `relUserHomes` the `HomeId` property of `Home.`

Try changing your code to the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "HomeId,Name")] Home home)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         db.Homes.Add(home);
         db.SaveChanges();
         RelUserHomes relUserHomes = new RelUserHomes();

         relUserHomes.HomeId = home.HomeId;
         db.RelUserHomes.Add(relUserHomes);
         db.SaveChanges();

    }
    return View(home);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this before, johnnyRose, but didn't work. The exception is like the db.SaveChange() has not receive the db.RelUserHomes.Add(relUserHomes). Thnks, anyway.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly the exception that is being thrown?

Comment: The exception is: "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details." Looks like that is not possible save changes twice in a method. I know that there's a simple way to do this, not necessarily like I did.

Comment: @Veloso you can call db.SaveChanges an arbitrary amount of times in one method, trust me. Why don't you look in the EntityValidationErrors property like the error suggests? And please post the entire models for Home and RelUserHomes.

Comment: Man, I think I figure what is causing this exception. As I'm doing it manualy I need to inform the a value for "relUserHomes.RelUserHomesId". I'm doing a test now to be sure.

Comment: Hey, I expressed myself wrong when I said that is not possible SaveChanges twice in a method, I read somewhere that is not a good pattern.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH for the help, man, this was driving me insane. You answer, that I also tried before, was the right answer all the time, in fact, my problem was the identity that was not configured for the field RelUserHomesId on table RelUserHomes. I figured it out when I implemented the override of SaveChanges().